# Why does this power series defined on the open unit disk take on every complex number infinitely often?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is a problem from Rudin's Real and complex analysis.

Let us take a sequence of integers $\{n_k\}$ with $n_1 >1$ and $n_{k+1} > 2kn_{k}.$ We let 
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 5^k z^{n_k}.$$
It is not too hard to prove that this series converges for $|z|<1,$ and that $f$ has no finite radial limits.

However, from what I understand, it is also true that $f$ attains every value $z \in \mathbb{C}$ infinitely often. I am stuck in how to prove this. One idea was to use Rouche's theorem, but that didn't get me too far. Any hint, or solution, is welcome.

**EDIT**
Here is an idea, which I do not know if it is correct or not. Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $f(z) = a$ for only finitely many values $z$ in the open unit disk. Then if we consider $f(z) -a,$ there is a polynomial $P(z)$ with the same zeros as $f(z)-a.$ Then if we let $$g(z) = P(z)/(f(z)-a),$$ $g$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk. If we had that $g$ could be extended to a holomorphic function on some open containing $D^1,$then we would be done, since $g(z) = 0$ on the boundary of the unit disk would contradict the maximal modulus principle. However, it is to me far from clear that $g$ extends. 
**EDIT 2**
Maybe it is true that we do not need that $g$ extends. Namely, since $g$ has no zeros inside of $D,$ it is true that $g(0) \neq 0.$So $|g(0)| >0.$ however, since $g(z) \to 0$ on the radial limits, this means that we should be able to derive a contradiction to the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: As you say yourself in the Edits, you view the maximum principle as a result that would need some stronger hypothesis than it does. Which version do you know, already?

Comment: @Did I am not sure I understand what you mean. Should I interpret this as saying that the argument in the second edit is correct? The one version I know is the following: If $f$ is a holomorphic function in a connected open set $U$of $\mathbb{C},$ and if the closure $\overline{D}(a,r)$of the unit disk of radius $r$ with center $a$ is in $U,$ then $|f(a)| \leq \max_{\theta} |f(a+r e^{i \theta})|$ with equality iff $f$ is constant in $U.$

Comment: And this version should essentially tell me that my argument is 2) is correct, but I am somewhat unsure.

Comment: The principle works if the function is holomorphic on an open ball and continuous on the closed ball, by... well, continuity.

Comment: @Did: Should I interpret your comment as saying that my argument in the second edit is correct?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Caution. That argument works only if $g$ _has_ radial limits ($0$) _everywhere_. But that would imply that $\lvert f\rvert$ has radial limits ($+\infty$) everywhere. Actually, for a continuity argument, radial limits aren't sufficient, you need actual limits.

Comment: @DanielFischer But is it not the case that $|f|$ has radial limits $+\infty$  everywhere, in this situation?

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it. Having radial limit $\infty$ everywhere, and not only almost everywhere looks difficult (I'm not sure whether it's possible). But you'd need an actual limit, not only radial or non-tangential, to continuously extend $g$ to the boundary.

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree that that is what needed to extend it continuously to the boundary. This is a problem from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis where he states that $h$ has no finite radial limits. Unless I made a mistake, I agree with him.

Comment: "No finite radial limits" doesn't mean the radial limits are $\infty$ everywhere. It's also possible that the radial limit doesn't exist at many points. Where exactly is that exercise from? Chapter 11, 12, …?

Comment: @DanielFischer Chapter 13!

Comment: Ah, the first thing to prove is that there is a $c > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z)\rvert > c\cdot 5^m$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1 - \frac{1}{n_m}$. That suffices. (Note that that doesn't imply radial limit $\infty$ everywhere, the function becomes small between any two such radii.) Apply the maximum modulus principle to $g$ on the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1 - 1/n_m\}$, and let $m \to \infty$ to obtain your contradiction. Since $P(z)$ is bounded on the closed unit disk, you get $\lvert g(0)\rvert < K\cdot 5^{-m}$ for every $m$, so $g(0) = 0$ contradicting the assumption.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice! So one must be more careful. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note on radial limits $\infty$ everywhere. It's impossible. You apply Baire and see $|f|>1$  on some $U=\{re^{it}: r> r_0, t \in (a,b)\}.$ But then $1/f$ is holomorphic and bounded in $U$ and has radial limits $0$ on a set of positive measure on $\partial U.$ Bounded holomorphic functions can't do that.